Request for assistance with expo-updates in SDK 50 without --public-url
I'm encountering difficulties when using expo-updates in Expo SDK 50. I recently migrated to SDK 50 and noticed that the --public-url option I was using previously is no longer available. I understand that this option has been replaced by another method, but I'm unsure of the correct approach.
Additional Details:
I'm using Expo SDK 50 in a bare project.
Prior to the migration, I was using expo-updates with the --public-url option to specify the public URL of my assets.
Now that the --public-url option is no longer available, I'm looking for an alternative to specify the public URL of my assets, ideally by hosting them on an S3 server.
What is the recommended method for specifying the public URL of assets in expo-updates without using --public-url?
How can I host my assets on an S3 server and use them with expo-updates in Expo SDK 50?
Can i not use eas?
Thank you very much for your assistance!

After search in the expo-updates code, it's work for me with:

AndroidManifest.xml

<meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATE_URL" android:value="https://your-url-to-access-config/android-index.json" />

<meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_RUNTIME_VERSION" android:value="1.0.0" />


Expo.plist

    <key>EXUpdatesRuntimeVersion</key>
    <string>1.0.0</string>


app.json
"runtimeVersion":"7.26"


After, you must have a script (in my case , a shell script) to generate a android-config.json and an ios-config.json to download the bundle and the assets of you app.
Your json contains:
{
    "releaseId": "A1A179D4-1129-43DC-B6CF-BDC473206E04",
    "commitTime": "2024-05-23T08:40:46Z",
    "bundleUrl": "https://your-url-to-access-the-js-bundle/index-your-app.js",
    "runtimeVersion": "1.0.0",
    "scheme": "myapp",
    "bundledAssets": [
        "asset_02b45454354335ccbff40c9",
        "asset_02b4545675f40c9",
     ]
}

The expo-update check the runtimeVersion and the commitTime to download the JS and apply.
⚠️ For iOS, the commitTime need the milliseconds
